# Mysql client doesn't connect to external server

Tags: mysql, linux, database-connection

I'm trying to connect to external mysql server through linux command line.
Whe I try for example:

```
mysql -h 102.235.10.77 -u root -p password
```

it gives the next error:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'190.201.179.249' (using password: NO)
```

Where **190.201.179.249** How you can see isn't the external server IP if not my local IP.

I already check out external connections at MySQL Server and 3306 port too, it Seems it's a local problem as if I can't connect to another IP than localhost.

regards.

Comment: Remove the space between `-p` and `password`, i.e. it should become `-ppassword`.

Comment: it's same, I have the same error just now with "using password: YES"... How I said, at the error shows that couldn't connect to my local IP when I am traying connect to other IP.

Comment: You have to create user `root@190.201.179.249` in the MySQL at 102.235.10.77. E.g. `CREATE USER 'root'@'190.201.179.249' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypass'`.